# Making a HTML Template

Tags: html, templates

So I want to create a template that looks something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf38Y.png (Not enough rep to post photos, I'm new)

(I'm in high school and have just completed a HTML class)

I know how to make the template but I want to make it so that I can just write the title, image location and content in a form or text document and have it create a new html page with the information.  I AM NOT ASKING YOU TO MAKE THE TEMPLATE FOR ME!  I also need it to be able to update the pages if I change the template.  Is this possible?  If so please leave any tutorials below.  I am NOT asking for you to write the code for me, I am just looking to see if this is possible and what languages it would require.

Thanks Much!

Comment: Have you tried Googling "html template"?

Comment: Yes, I find templates for html that can be modified.  I am looking for a way to input text and images and have the system create a html page for me.  I will also need to update the footer and I don't want to have to go through each page to make the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you will have to write an application, which will convert the data given by the user into an HTML webpage. This will require using JavaScript, HTML and CSS together. You can create an HTML page which will have `<input>` tags in it. Then using JavaScript libraries, such as FileSaver.js, you can create an HTML file and add data to it with JavaScript, probably using `.appendChild()` method. This was for a webapp, that will work in a browser, for desktop app you can use other programming languages or use Adobe AIR to package your webapp for desktop.